# Swift: How to rm Alamofire get request One by One in loop

Tags: arrays, swift, asynchronous, alamofire

I am a beginner in swift and I have come across a case where I need to run AlamoFire GET request in a loop. But As far as i know , the Alamofire Get request is an Asynchronous call and calling it in loop will create a number of threads.

The requirement is :

1. I have an array of URLs
2. The array has to be traversed in a loop
3. URL on each index has to be called through AlamoFire GET request
4. The received data through the request will be added to an array of
       data
5. After the last data is saved in the array, a
       CollectionView.reload call should be called

Pseudo code is as follows:

```
    for bookmarkURL in bookmarks
        Alamofire.request(.GET, bookmarkURL ).responseJSON
                { response in switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    x[i] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject] // saving data

                case .Failure(let error):
                     print("the error for \(self.bookmarkURL) is \(error) ")
                }
        i++
        if i == bookmarks.count{
           collectionView.reload()
          break}
}
```

can anyone tell me how should I do it in sequence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Make `bookmarks` array as class property.
- Add a class property `index` to store index value (`Int`) while traversing the `bookmarks` array
- Add a function to make API call and call it recursively.

Here is the code:

```
func getData() {
    var x = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, bookmarks[index]).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            x[self.index] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject] // saving data
            self.index = self.index + 1
            if self.index < self.bookmarks.count {
                self.getData()
            }else {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("the error for \(self.bookmarks[self.index]) is \(error) ")
            if self.index < self.bookmarks.count {
                self.getData()
            }else {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this way your request will be made only when previous is completed thus making it sequentially instead of parallel and you can also reload the collectionView only after the last request is completed.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reload your collection view only after receiving whole the data, you can use `dispatch_group` like,

```
    let group = dispatch_group_create() // create a group.

    dispatch_group_enter(group) // enter the group just before create the request 

    dispatch_group_leave(group)//leave the group on completion closure
    dispatch_group_notify(group, group) { 
        //reload your collection view 
    }
```

Full code

```
    for bookmarkURL in bookmarks {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        Alamofire.request(.GET, bookmarkURL ).responseJSON { response in 
        switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                x[i] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject] // saving data

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("the error for \(self.bookmarkURL) is \(error) ")
            }
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
        }
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(group, group) {
         collectionView.reload()
    }
```

Note: if your bookmarks array is too large, better not to do it in a loop.
For that you can use following code

```
func loadBookmarkAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if index >= bookmarks.count {
        collectionView.reload()
        return
    }
    let bookmarkURL = bookmarks[index]
    Alamofire.request(.GET, bookmarkURL ).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            x[index] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject] // saving data

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("the error for \(bookmarkURL) is \(error) ")

        }
        self.loadBookmarkAtIndex(index+1)
    }
}
```

And call `self.loadBookmarkAtIndex(0)` from where you are initiating the data retrieve.

Comment: Will the AlamoFire GET request be called one by one, in loop , through this method?

Comment: No, but it will wait for complete all requests, to execute the notify group. If you want to call alamofire request one by one, better to use other techiques.

Comment: Tried the code for downloading images from many URLs, but the method dispatch_group_notify doesn't get called. Any ideas? By the way the same code used to work just fine a few days back

Answer (score 2):

I think you should reload item of collection view each time you get the response from the sever regarding to the response received.

Here is the solution:

```
let x : NSMutableArray  = NSMutableArray.init(capacity: bookmarks.count)

for var i in 0 ..< x.count {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, bookmarkURL ).responseJSON
                { response in switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):

    x.insertObject(JSON as! [String : AnyObject], atIndex:i)
                //    x[i] = // saving data
    // <reload relative item cell of collectionView>

                case .Failure(let error):
                     print("the error for \(self.bookmarkURL) is \(error) ")
                }
        i+=1

    }
```

Hope above code will help you.